# Getting java.net.ConnectException: your endpoint configuration is wrong when running ./yarn command

Tags: java, hadoop

I am extremely new to Hadoop, know almost nothing about this concept.

I just started a class and attempted to install a Hadoop. I simply followed instructions in the notes

And finally executed the following command

```
$ ./yarn jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop2.9.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples2.9.1.jar wordcount /in /out
```

The output was multiple 'retrying to connect' statements with 'java.net.ConnectException: your endpoint configuration is wrong' at the ends

For some reason I can't find the 'jps' command to check if services are running

What can I check?

Thank you for your help!

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxuYr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, my Java wasn't fully installed; thus, I had to finalized the installation

```
yum list java*devel*
sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
```

That let me use the jps command

Then checked hdfs-site.xml for a property dfs.datanode.data.dir

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:///data/1/dfs/dn</value>
</property>
```

Since the NameNode is formatted you don’t have an option other than formatting (deleting) the contents in DataNode as well. So go to the directory location specified in dfs.datanode.data.dir and issue a delete on that directory across all DataNodes.

Once the data directories are formatted in all DataNodes, I restarted the DataNode process on all DataNodes

Then checked for failed cluster ID's in Datanode's logs

Copied to clipboard datanode clusterID for example, CID-8bf63244-0510-4db6-a949-8f74b50f2be9

and run following command under HADOOP_HOME/bin directory

```
./hdfs namenode -format -clusterId CID-8bf63244-0510-4db6-a949-8f74b50f2be9
```

Everything worked !